# OData v4 modelling - do I need to use [Key] and [ForeignKey]?

Tags: entity-framework, odata, asp.net-web-api2

All the tutorials I've found on OData v4 seem to conflate the OData model with an EF storage model.

It's hard to work out what's needed for EF and what's for OData.

Do I need to use the `KeyAttribute` and `ForeignKeyAttribute` on the appropriate properties in my model if I am just building a model for the OData service?

I'm using a different model for storage that may be quite different to the OData model. I still want the OData model to look and feel like a relational DB model, and work with data analysis tools, abeit a kind of contrived facade.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I kind of agree that sometimes it's confusing to differentiate the attributes of EF and OData and sorry I don't have enough knowledge to give a direct answer. But there is one [OData Web API sample implementation](https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/Scenarios/TripPin/src) that doesn't rely on EF . You can take a look at this sample which uses CLR class and in-memory data. For example, in the sample is that it uses [key] and other attributes but these are in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` .

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the link to the example, in the models, the author has used `[Key]` to inform the model builder about the primary key. Possibly, this was out of habit, I'd have to remove the attribs, build the project and connect a full-spec OData consumer to know for sure, but at the moment Power[Pivot|Query] can't use v4.